# Design pattern to decouple from third party lib

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am trying  decouple a third party library's abstract class. I want to expose a new abstract class which will be exposed to the users rather than the library provided class.
I initially tried using an adapter but that stills add the import for the third party lib in the adapter class.

I added code below explaining my **new** approach.

```
   // third party lib
    abstract class ThirdParty<S> { 
       public abstract S doAction(S s);
    }
    // my goal here is to expose a different abstract class which is    decoupled from third party lib
    // exposed to other modules, rather than exposing the third party lib
    abstract class ExposedAbstractClass<S> {
        public abstract S doAction(S source);
        // get hold of type using guava lib
        private final TypeToken<S> typeToken = new TypeToken<S>(getClass()) { };
        public Class<S> getSourceClass() { return (Class<S>) typeToken.getClass()
    }

  // internal class
   class Builder<S> extends ThirdPartyLib<S> {
       ExposedAbstractClass exposed;
       public Builder(ExposedAbstractClass exposed) {
         this.exposed = exposed;
       }
       @Override
       public S doAction(S s) {
         return (S) exposed.doAction(s);
       }
   }
   //my approach breaks here when i try to invoke builder 
   class InvokeThirdParty {
       public void invoke (ExposedAbstractClass exposed) {
         Class type = exposed.getSourceClass();
         Builder<type> builder = new Builder(exposed); //doesn't work since Class is runtime type, and T is compile time type 
       }
   }
```

Any guidance in terms of which design pattern to follow here would be very helpful.

Comment: `I initially tried using an adapter but that stills add the import for the third party lib in the adapter class` Looks to be ok since adaptor includes not only your application side but also the third party side. Could you please explain this point ?

Comment: @GauravJ Yes, as you said adapter  would introduce the the third party side in the exposed class. I was trying to avoid that. My goal was to expose only a standalone abstract class which doesnt have any dependency on the third party lib. I also tried using a bridge pattern but not quite sure, how to achieve the decoupling given generics. Also maybe my overall approach is wrong here to decouple the third party library and right approach would be to go with adapter or facade here and not worry about decoupling the third party.

Comment: You should push your third party dependency to all the way to the edge of your application. Declare interface and your internal class should depend on those. I don't see anything wrong in doing this. Adaptor pattern or bridge pattern are way to achieve this but you would still have class dependency in your application. Your core classes would not know about third party (your adaptor or bridge would know). If you are looking to remove jar dependency from your application, then you need to use something similar to java.util.ServiceLocator but I doubt that this is your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [GuaravJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479136/gauravj) answer, you could isolate the third party dependency and use an Adaptor or Bridge pattern to invoke the third party library from there. I believe this would be an adequate decoupled solution.

However, it would seem your intent is to **remove** the `import`, hence the dependency?

### As an alternative, how about implementing **Reflection** on the `ThirdParty` class?

Java is compatible with **Reflection-oriented-programming**. This lets you inspect and examine classes and invoke their methods dynamically at runtime. It would eliminate the dependency and the `import` statement for the `ThirdParty` class.

In general terms, with Reflection, you have to locate the class and inspect its methods. In this case I'm assuming knowledge of the `doAction()` method from `ThirdPartyClass`.

### **A simple Java reflection example following the idea of your code excerpt:**

### Not using reflection

```
// import ThirdPartyLibrary statement somewhere here

// Instantiating object with concrete class that implements methods from ThirdParty. From your code now, it would be "Builder".
ThirdParty<S> thirdPartyObject = new ThirdPartyImp<S>();

// Invoking doAction method which returns an S object    
S foo = thirdPartyObject.doAction();
```

---

### Using reflection

```
// Inspect the class finding it using its path and instantiating an object
ThirdParty<S> thirdPartyObject = Class.forName("classpath.to.ThirdPartyImp").newInstance(); // Using a concrete class to instantiate.

// Finding the doAction method. This is assuming we have knowledge that a method with this name exists. Reflection could go as deep as not knowing the methods and having some control structure inspecting them.
Method doAction = thirdPartyObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("doAction", new Class<?>[0]);

// Do action is invoked and it returns an object S.
S foo = thirdPartyObject.invoke(thirdPartyObject);
```

---

### Further reading and notes

- [Oracle Java official documentation on reflection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html)
- [Java Reflection example tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1789/java-reflection-example-tutorial)
- [Wikipedia Reflection (Computer Science) definition and examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming))